# Получить доступ к redux state внутри hoc

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-final-form

Написал небольшой `hoc` для `react-final-form`.

```
const withForm = (validate, getInitialValues = noop) => (WrappedForm) => {
  const EnhacedForm = ({ onSubmit, ...ownProps }) => (
    <ReactFinalForm
      validate={validate}
      initialValues={getInitialValues(ownProps)}
      render={renderProps => <WrappedForm {...ownProps} {...renderProps} />}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    />
  );

  return EnhacedForm;
};
```

Используется так:

```
const SignIn = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Username />
    <Password />
    <Button type="submit">Войти<Button/>
  </Form>
);

export default withForm()(SignInForm);
```

Если для формы требуются `initialValues` то нужно имплементировать `getInitialValues`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { phone: state.user.phone };
}

function getInitialValues(ownProps) {
  return { phone: 'here is my phone from redux state' };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
  form(null, getInitialValues)(SignInForm),
);
```

Возник вопрос как получить `initialValues` данные из redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую.
Вот пример для достижения макс. гибкости. Хотя по сути я просто скопировал схему работы redux-form, возможно лучше глянуть их исходники.

```
// чтобы дальше было понятней
type WithFormOptions = {
    onSubmit?: () => any;
    initialValues?: any;
    validate?: () => any;
    onSubmitFail?: () => any; // для примера в самом конце
}


const withForm = (options: WithFormOptions) => (WrappedForm) => {
  return ({ onSubmit, initialValues, validate, ...ownProps }) => {
      const ownFormProps = { onSubmit, initialValues, validate};
      const formProps = { ...ownFormProps, ...options };          
      // или может так:  ...options, ...ownFormProps };

      return (
        <ReactFinalForm
           {...formProps}
           render={renderProps => <WrappedForm {...ownProps} {...renderProps}
        />
      );
   }

};
```

Форма без обёрток, так как обёртки скорее лучше запулить в контейнере

```
export const SignInForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Username />
    <Password />
    <Button type="submit">Войти<Button/>
  </Form>
);

export default SignInForm;
```

Далее контейнер я бы сделал так

```
export default compose(
    connect(s => ({ initialValues: ....})),
    withForm({
        onSubmit: () => ...,
        validate: () => ...,
    })
)(SignInForm)
```

Дальше вызываем контейнер, к примеру даже так:

```
<SignInFormContainer onSubmitFail={console.warn} />
```

Comment: В итоге вот хороший пример https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createReduxForm.js#L277 , начиная с 277 строчки начинается hoc

Comment: и кажется я упустил присутствие handleSubmit , но идея надеюсь ясна!